# Calculating the arc of a curve

Tags: integration, arc-length

I need to find the arc length from the function $$ y^{2}= - 2.6\times x$$

Will the result change if I replace the function with? $$x = \frac{y^{2}}{-2.6}$$ I also ask you to check my answer, I did it: $$\frac{y\times\sqrt{1+\frac{y^{2}}{1.69}}+\ln\mid\frac{y}{1.3}+\sqrt{1+\frac{y^{2}}{1.69}}\mid}{3}$$

[Solving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im39H.jpg)

Comment: No, the result will not change. Also, arc length is a scalar quantity, not an algebraic expression. Since $x$ is a function of $y$, you'll need to submit your limits of integration.

Comment: I understand that. I decided to check if I had calculated the integral correctly, and then substitute the limits of integration

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm afraid that's not the correct antiderivative. The correct one is $\sqrt{\frac{1.69+y}{1.69}}y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1.69}}(\frac{1}{3}(1.69+y)^{\frac{3}{2}}-1.69\sqrt{1.69+y})+ C$

Comment: I have solved this integral, the answer is completely different. I solved it as an integral that boils down to myself, I also attached a link to a photo with my solution, please tell me what I did wrong (The answer to the photo is underlined with a green line)